# using concat and group_concat function in one mysql query

Tags: mysql

hi guys is it posible to use GROUP_CONCAT and CONCAT function in same query i am trying to use

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(idmaterial,percent)) as 'material' FROM a_m where idarticle=1
```

to get result like this in one row one column

```
material
----------
1 5%10 6%80 1%10
```

please help me with your ideas thanks a lot here is my table thanks a lot for your helps

```
    idarticle |idmaterial| percent
    ---------- ---------- ----------
    1              5        10
    ---------- ---------- ----------
    1              6        80    
    ---------- ---------- ----------
    1              1        10
    ---------- ---------- ----------
    2              1        90
    ---------- ---------- ----------
    2              2        10
    ---------- ---------- ----------
```

Comment: Just to clarify, GROUP_CONCAT() is used for collating multiple rows into a single delimited string, in your case all idmaterial's where idartical=1.  CONCAT() on the other hand is used for joining strings together.  CONCAT works on strings, so CONCAT('string1', 'string2', 'string3') to make string1string2string3 while GROUP_CONCAT would take your rows above and return 5,6,1 (for example) for idarticle = 1.  I hope this comment helps explain the difference and so why they are able to work together :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` goes with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT idarticle, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( idmaterial, '%', percent ) SEPARATOR ' ' ) as materials
FROM a_m
GROUP BY idarticle
```

And to put in one column you can use:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT( idarticle, ' ', 
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( idmaterial, '%', percent ) SEPARATOR ' ' ) ) AS CHAR) as material
FROM a_m
GROUP BY idarticle
```

Comment: thanks a lot almost work but i am getting [BLOB - 7B] result instead of percent values do you have any idea what is wrong